# Protect NDEF Message on Mifare Classic Tag Android

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, ndef

In my android application, I am reading data from a mifare classic tag using [the code on this website](http://mifareclassicdetectiononandroid.blogspot.com/2011/04/reading-mifare-classic-1k-from-android.html). Since it requires authentication, I can change the Key B of some sectors, and protect my data from being read by others.

However, instead of my own formatted data, I'd like to store ndef messages. The code I use for reading ndef is as following

```
Tag myTag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(myTag);
NdefMessage ndefMesg = ndefTag.getCachedNdefMessage();
NdefRecord[] ndefRecords = ndefMesg.getRecords();
byte[] mesg = ndefRecords[0].getPayload();
String info = new String(mesg, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

It doesn't require any authentication, so my problem is how can I protect an ndef message from being read by others?

**Edit:** When I say protect I don't mean making the tag readonly. I mean only I, or whoever has the key, can write ndef message to the tag

Comment: Why not just read the raw data and parse the payload as a NdefMessage?

Comment: I don't get what you are suggesting. Could you explain more?

Comment: Why you doesn´t crypto the message? Only you could decrypto again on read.